# "Regex pattern did not match", even though they should - pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, exception, pytest

I am trying to match the string in this error:

```py
for warning in args:
    if not isinstance(warning, str):
        with StaticvarExceptionHandler():
            raise TypeError(f"Configure.suppress() only takes string arguments. Current type: {type(warning)}")
```

with the one in this pytest test:

```py
with pytest.raises(
    TypeError,
    match = "Configure.suppress() only takes string arguments. Current type: .*"
):
    Configure.suppress('ComplicatedTypeWarning', 1)
```

It should match, but I am getting this error:

```
E    AssertionError: Regex pattern did not match.
E     Regex: 'Configure.suppress() only takes string arguments. Current type: .*'
E     Input: "Configure.suppress() only takes string arguments. Current type: <class 'int'>"
```

Keep in mind that for all other tests that I use `.*`, everything works fine.

I am very new to Regex, so I apologise if this is actually a really stupid question. Also, I've seen many many questions like these, but they were all in Java and not the same case as mine, so I couldn't find a solution. Feel free to flag this as a duplicate and link a matching question, though.

Comment: Symbols like `.`, `(` and `)` (among others) have special meaning in regex and should be escaped with ``\``. You regex should be: `Configure\.suppress\(\) only takes string arguments\. Current type: .*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parentheses have a special meaning in Regex, for marking capture groups and a few other things, see https://regex101.com (select "Python" on the left menu to get Python-specific regex explanations, since they vary from language to language).

You need to escape them

```py
match = "Configure.suppress\\(\\) only takes string arguments. Current type: .*"
```

or (note the `r` before the `"`, for a "raw string")

```py
match = r"Configure.suppress\(\) only takes string arguments. Current type: .*"
```

Technically you don't need to escape those periods, since a period will match any non-newline character, and it's unlikely that there will be another error with a similar name that has a different character in place of those periods, but if you want to fix that use either of these:

```py
match = "Configure\\.suppress\\(\\) only takes string arguments\\. Current type: .*"
```

or (note the `r` before the `"`, for a "raw string")

```py
match = r"Configure\.suppress\(\) only takes string arguments\. Current type: .*"
```

Comment: Lovely! Also, that site is very very good. Thank you so much.